# Customize Instagram widget on a Dashing.io dashboard

Tags: ruby, json, instagram-api, dashing

I have set up a dashboard using dashing with a number of (mostly) existing widgets. That worked so far - [see production dashboard here](https://dyscribe.herokuapp.com) *(work in progress)*.

Now I would like to have an Instagram widget that displays the `n` lastest images taken by `username`.
I have found a widget that will display images by `long` and `lat` and also was able to get my tokens configured, so I can talk to the Instagram API.

Here's the code of my current widget [originally from @mjamieson's gist on github](https://gist.github.com/mjamieson/5278790).

```
require 'instagram'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

# Instagram Client ID from http://instagram.com/developer
Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = ENV['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID']
  config.client_secret = ENV['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET']
end

# Latitude, Longitude for location
instadash_location_lat = '45.429522'
instadash_location_long = '-75.689613'


SCHEDULER.every '10m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  photos = Instagram.media_search(instadash_location_lat,instadash_location_long)
  if photos
    photos.map do |photo|
      { photo: "#{photo.images.low_resolution.url}" }
    end
  end
  send_event('instadash', photos: photos)
end
```

I got this to work, but would like to modify the given API call to only display images taken by me / a user of my choice. Unfortunately I don't understand ruby or json enough to figure out what the Instagram API documentation wants me to do.

I found the following url

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token={acces-token}`

and tried it (with my credentials filled in). It returned json data correctly including my images (among other data).

How can I modify the given code to display images by username instead of location?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'instagram'

# Instagram Client ID from http://instagram.com/developer
Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = ENV['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID']
  config.client_secret = ENV['INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET']
  config.access_token = ENV['INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN']
end

user_id = ENV['INSTAGRAM_USER_ID']

SCHEDULER.every '2m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
  photos = Instagram.user_recent_media("#{user_id}")
  if photos
    photos.map! do |photo|
      { photo: "#{photo.images.low_resolution.url}" }
    end
  end
  send_event('instadash', photos: photos)
end
```

### Explaination

1.) In addition to the `client_id` and `client_secret` I had defined before, I just needed to add my `access_token` to the `Instagram.configure` section.

2.) The `SCHEDULER` was correctly working, but needed to call `Instagram.user_recent_media("#{user_id}")` instead of `Instagram.media_search(instadash_location_lat,instadash_location_long)`

3.) To do that I had to set a second missing variable for `user_id`

Now the call gets recent media filtered by user ID and outputs it into the dashing widget.

Thanks for the participation and hints! That pointed me into the right direction of the documentation and helped me to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an `access_token` to get content from some user. Take a look at [sample application](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem#sample-application) on gem page.
It seems you need something like this:

```
# here we take access token from session, assuming you already got it
# sometime before and stored it there for future use
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
photos = client.user_recent_media
```

And this example how to get this access_token using OAuth2 browser authorization and sinatra app:

```
require "sinatra"
require "instagram"

enable :sessions

CALLBACK_URL = "http://localhost:4567/oauth/callback"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
  config.client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
  # For secured endpoints only
  #config.client_ips = '<Comma separated list of IPs>'
end

get "/" do
  '<a href="/oauth/connect">Connect with Instagram</a>'
end

get "/oauth/connect" do
  redirect Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
end

get "/oauth/callback" do
  response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL)
  session[:access_token] = response.access_token
  redirect "/nav"
end
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply! I'll look into this and see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Ok @Alexey-Shein I have a `access_token` set up and stored inside my local `.env` file - I already checked the given part of the documentation but found it not be the right solution - as my authorization works fine and I receive user data in `json` format but don't know how to select the right data from that json to be put in the `send_event` of the `scheduler` from my code snippet.